Understanding the additive white Gaussian noise (AWGN) representation
In my research work in wireless communication, I came across an equation of received signal wherein the AWGN is denoted by $n\sim\mathcal{C}\mathcal{N}(\textbf{0},\textbf{I}_L)$.
Note that dimension of received signal is $1\times L$ and dimension of noise is also $1\times L$.
I understood that $\mathcal{C}\mathcal{N}$ in AWGN represents Complex Gaussian but my query is what does $(\textbf{0},\textbf{I}_L)$ in AWGN indicates?
Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Complete guess: the 0 vector and a covariance matrix which is the identity matrix of dimensions LxL?

Thank u so much sir for ur reply

If dimension of noise is a vector ($1\times L$) then how $\textbf{I}_L$ can be a matrix ?

Can you clarify your question in the comments by adding an edit to your original question? Have you looked up the definition of the multivariate normal distribution? What is your confusion?

I’m not familiar with complex normal distributions, but for multi variate normal distributions that aren’t complex, you’ve got a covariance matrix for a random gaussian vector - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution

see how in the link I sent you, for a vector of length kx1, there’s a kxk covariance matrix.

Yes, $I_{L}$ is an $L$-by-$L$ identity matrix.
